# I need to Count word in 2D grid of characters in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, nested

Can you please correct this JAVASCRIPT CODE for the following array

```
Input : array =[    
         ['D','D','D','G','D','D'],  
         ['B','B','D','E','B','S'],  
         ['B','S','K','E','B','K'],  
         ['D','D','D','D','D','E'],  
         ['D','D','D','D','D','E'],  
         ['D','D','D','D','D','G']  
        ]  
     str= "GEEKS"
```

Output :2
I tried with the javascript code but I am not getting the answer

```
let array = [['D','D','D','G','D','D'],      
             ['B','B','D','E','B','S'],      
             ['B','S','K','E','B','K'],      
             ['D','D','D','D','D','E'],      
             ['D','D','D','D','D','E'],      
             ['D','D','D','D','D','G']]
```

> `function wordCount(array, str) {`
> `let count = 0;`
> `for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {`
> `for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {`
> `if (array[i][j] = str)`
> `count++;`
> `}`
> `}`
> `return count;`
> `}`
> `console.log(wordCount(array, 'GEEKS'));`

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 1? I don't see another one than the one on the right from bottom to top.. Also, are diagonals possible? Hint: this is going to be much more complex than what you tried, you need to assemble the letters yourself, currently your are always comparing with a single char

Comment: your code is not executable AT ALL - and even if it were, there's no way it would output 2 - only 0 - a single letter can never match a word - please show the code that produces a result of 2 - in fact, please produce code that RUNS

Comment: @JaromandaX at least he need `==` in `if` (it will not help, but anyway)

Comment: @Anton - oh, yeah, his code would produce 30, not 0 (definitely not 2) - oh, I see, he EXPECTS 2, and has written code that doesn't even run

Comment: The task is not obvious. For example can we find 'PEEKP' in this array: [[P,E],[K,E]] ?

Comment: Speaking of errors, in addition ti @Anton's comment, you need to fill your array with strings (`[['D','D','D','G','D','D'], ...`), currently Javascript is trying to fill it with variables `D`, `G` etc and doesn't find them

Comment: I am beginer and I am stuck up

Comment: Actually the goal of StackOverflow is not to provide free code writing services, so few people here will gladly write all the code for you, particularly when the requirements are imprecise. If you are a beginner I recommend first to add all the details to the question (why you expect the result to be 2? what are all the valid ways to find a word in your array?). Then second, generally speaking in coding, when you are stuck, break the task in smaller tasks, log intermediate values, and don't hesitate to go step by step, even on a piece of paper, to find what is the logic

Comment: I found this program in C++ from other site and thought to do in Javascript.

Comment: @Prashant read the comments above

Comment: Hello, I am unable to count woe in the array... The output is wrong. how to debug

Comment: let array = [["w","e","w","o"],      
             ["w","o","e","w"],        
             ["o","w","o","e"]];      
let count = 0;     
function wordCount(array, str) {
    function wordSplit(str) {
  var newStr = str.split('');
   return newStr;
  };
  console.log(wordSplit('woe'));
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
       if (array[i][j] === str[0])
          count++;
      };
    };
      return count;
  };
 console.log(wordCount(array,'woe'));